# How do I get javadocs for PDFBox displayed in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, javadoc, pdfbox

Using Netbeans and am able to execute the PDFBox utility just fine.
But there are no javadocs for PDFBox.  The NB's context display says "Javadoc not found".  Tried building them from the IDE, but after 10 minutes of maven messages, it failed.  How do I get PDFBox javadocs into Netbeans?  Also cannot get to source code even though I have it in library.

Comment: What happens if you download the sources, and add the zip or the extracted zip as source? Go to project properties, libraries, go to the line with the pdfbox jar, click "edit", then sources, then fin the path. Or are you using maven? (Re the not working build - that would be interesting too, if you have the time, open a separate question and include the output)

Comment: I made a quick test… it works for me if I extract the src zip, and then point netbeans to the appropriate directory, i.e. the root of the pdfbox subproject. Like "C:\Users\Username\somedirectory\pdfbox-2.0.13-src\pdfbox-2.0.13\pdfbox". Please tell whether that worked for you. If not, please tell what versions / jar files you are using.

Answer (score 0):

To view the source and help documentation for `PDFBox`:

- From the [download page for PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi):

  - Download the jar file for the code (e.g. *pdfbox-app-2.0.13.jar*).
  - Download the zip file for the source (e.g. *pdfbox-2.0.13-src.zip*)
- Select **Tools > Libraries** to open the **Add Library Manager** window. From there:

  - You will be positioned on the **Classpath** tab. Click the **Add JAR/Folder...** button and navigate to the downloaded **jar** file.
  - Click the **Sources** tab, click the **Add JAR/Folder...** button, and navigate to the downloaded **zip** file.
  - Click the **Javadoc** tab, click the **Add URL...** button, and enter the **Javadoc URL** for PDFBox (e.g. https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.13/javadocs/).
  - Click the **OK** button to close the **Add Library Manager** window.
- Then, from the Java source of your project that uses PDFBox:

  - Position the cursor over some PDFBox class or method and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to view its source.
  - Position the cursor over some PDFBox class or method, and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to open the PDFBox Javadoc in the browser.
  - Position the cursor over some PDFBox class or method, and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to open autocompletion. Here's a sample screen shot for that:

    [image: autoComplete]

Comment: Best instructions.....thanx so much.  (Didn't Know NB's used web to access javadocs.  Cool.)

Comment: @Bcwilmot You can specify the location of the Javadoc for a NetBeans library as a local zip/jar file, or as a URL. In the case of PDFBox I couldn't find a download for its Javadocs, so specifying a URL was the only choice, though specifying a local zip/jar file is usually preferable.